# Are "V" brake rims safe to use with discs

Tags: brakes, rims, wheel-building

I'm new to this forum and would like to ask if it is safe to use a V brake rim with a disc? I'm using Shimano Deore M555 hubs with discs laced to Mavic EX 721 32 hole rims and DB spokes. Apologies if this has been queried before.
Thanks in anticipation.
Paul C (Chaz)

Comment: @Paparazzi - ??? Why does a rim used with disk brakes need a "brake surface"?

Comment: @Paparazzi - Uh, why would anyone need to "make sure" of this, if using the rim with disk brakes.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Otherwise it is not a V brake rim.  Let it go.

Answer (score 7):

Not only is it safe it is fairly common. When disc brake became more affordable many after market manufacturers sold dual brake wheels. Disc hubs and "V" brake rims. Just don't use "V" brakes on a disc only specific rim. The dual use wheel may have been a way to limit new inventory to one type of wheelset.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and a good comment about the single wheelset.

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes. That said disc brakes have higher radial torsion, so the most important factor is spoke lacing and tension.

It is a common practice as "V" brake rims are more common and usually cheaper for a similar quality as disc specific rims.

The other way around is not an option though, obviously!!

Comment: Thanks for that and yes, I did wonder about the lacing and radial torsion but this way round I can retain my V brakes if absolutely necessary and keep the spare tyres on the wheels for emergencies.

Comment: It is a good point that if the V-brake rims were really lightweight then there would be a very slight risk of spoke nipples pulling through the rim, due to the high torque when braking.  But these would either be track rims or BSO rims.